# RTMPT and NetConnection

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, rtmp

How i can connect to FluorineFx RTMPT server?
And how can i configure FluorineFx RTMPT server?
Can i start FluorineFx RTMPT server without IIS installed?

Is there any tutorial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to configure a FluorineFx server.

I can tell you that you do not need IIS for RTMPT to work. RTMPT just uses port 80 instead of 1935.

You will be able to connect to the server the same way as you would normally do. You will probably just need to specify the port to connect to now.

Example:

```
NetConnection conn = new NetConnection();
conn.connect("rtmpt://127.0.0.1/app");
```

The following MIGHT work, haven't tested:

```
NetConnection conn = new NetConnection();
conn.connect("rtmp://127.0.0.1:80/app");
```

Hope this helped.